# How to return dates where task end_date is true in javascript

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, javascript-objects, dayofweek

I want to return not one date but all the task that has ended.

Assumning my end_date Task are

- Jan. 30 2020
- Jan. 30 2017
- Jan. 30 1987

so far the code below only return

- Jan. 30 2020

**My code is**

```
const CalTaskHasEnded = Task => {
      return new Date(task.end_date).getDay() === new Date().getDay();
   };
```

But this only returns one date from the list of dates where task has ended.

How to write this code to be able to return all the tasks that has gotten its end_date. i.e task that has ended.

Comment: Please show the object. Click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and produce a [mcve] - you likely meant to use a filter

Comment: Also why only test the day?, then ended date Jan 30 2021 will also be returned once you succeed in filtering proper

Comment: Hi mplungjan thanks for the comment, I think the main issue now is how the line of code i gave here return just one date out of the list of dates in the backend. Do you mean i havent supply enough information? How the end_date is accessed is coming from the task.end_date .

Comment: You are also not testing the end date is true now - you are comparing a day number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks RamiReddy for your time, I have solved this like this

```
const calTaskHasEnded = Task => {
    if (task.has_ended){
       return new Date().getDay();
       }
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

you can check date before or not

```
const CalTaskHasEnded = (task:Task ) => {
      return new Date(task.end_date).getTime() <= new Date().getTime();
   };
 
 let tasks = [{
    end_date:'Jan. 30 2020'
},{
    end_date:'Jan. 30 2017'
},
{
    end_date:'Jan. 30 1987'
},
{
    end_date:'Jan. 30 2027'
}]

console.log(tasks.filter(CalTaskHasEnded));
```